# Tree Diagram: What is the probability that a customer purchases the basic or classic car wash if they vacuum their car?

Tags: probability, statistics

This equation comes from Edgenuity's course of Statistics, and I am taking the course as a high school senior. I understand that to find $P(A$ | $B)$, one divides $P(A$ and $B)$ by $P(B)$. Also, to find $P(A$ or $B)$, one adds $P(A)$ and $P(B)$. I attempt to do this in my solving of the problem below:

> **A car wash has three different types of washes: basic, classic, and ultimate. Based on records, 45% of customers get the basic wash, 35%
> get the classic wash, and 20% get the ultimate wash. Some customers
> also vacuum out their cars after the wash. The car wash records show
> that 10% of customers who get the basic wash, 25% of customers who get
> the classic wash, and 60% of customers who get the ultimate wash also
> vacuum their cars. The probabilities are displayed in the tree
> diagram.**
>
> [image]
>
> **What is the probability that a randomly selected customer purchases the basic or classic car wash if they vacuum their car?**

**First**, I found the total probability of having any type of wash and having the car vacuumed $(0.2525)$ by adding each probability of having whatever type of wash and the probability of vacuuming after using that type of wash (i.e., $(0.45 * 0.10) + (0.35 * 0.25) + (0.2 * 0.6) = 0.2525$).

**Second**, I added $P($Basic and Vacuum$)$ and $P($Classic and Vacuum$)$, which is $0.1325$, because $P(A$ or $B)$ is $P(A)$ $+$ $P(B)$.

**Lastly**, I divided $0.1325$ by $0.2525$ to find $P($Basic or Classic | Vacuum$)$ because $P(A$ | $B)$ $=$ $P(A$ and $B)$ $÷$ $P(B)$. The answer is approximately $0.52$. Are my methods and answer correct? If not, please explain why.

Comment: +1 : for query presentation, a pleasure to read your analysis.  Very high quality query.  In evaluating your query, I regard it as irrelevant whether you have a flaw in your analysis.  In fact, I completely agree with your analysis.  Your methods were spot on.  The only caveat that I would mention is that in general, the formula for $p(A ~\text{or}~ B) = p(A) + p(B) - p(A ~\text{and}~ B).$  The formula that you used is good, only so long as $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive (i.e. disjoint) events.